# Android readCharacteristic not working with UUID.fromString

Tags: java, android

My app interfaces to BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). I store the UUIDS in an `ArrayList`.

```
chars.add(UUID.fromString(CONFIG_UUID));//config etc etc
```

When I read the characteristic from the bottom of the list:

```
readCharacteristic (chars.get(chars.size() - 1));
```

I should get a callback to `onCharacteristicRead`, I don't.

If I do this:

```
readCharacteristic (UUID.fromString(CONFIG_UUID));
```

Then all works as it should.

The UUID is stored as:

```
public static final String CONFIG_UUID = "03656ba0-adce-49a2-842d-9c5a71fc65e1";
```

Comment: I assume you have race conditions or multithreading issue? `ArrayList` is not thread safe.

Comment: @rich so what do you get when you call `readCharacteristic (chars.get(chars.size() - 1));`? Do you get an error?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I don't really understand the issue yet so don't want to waste people's time.  The OnCharacteristicRead is now working but it will fail if one of the characteristic reads fails since then there is no subsequent callback.  I have four characteristics to read but reading two of them always fails.  They both have read/write properties set...  Investigating...